# Android: find the id of the inflated buttons

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I have inflated buttons using the following codes, and would like to swap the location of the 2 buttons selected using simple `TranslateAnimation`.

## Codes:

```
    for (int k = 1; k <= quotient; k++) 
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(button_width,row_height);
        params3.setMargins(button_margin, button_margin, button_margin, button_margin);
        btn_right = new Button(this);
        btn_right.setId(idd);
        final int id_ = btn_right.getId();
        btn_right.setText(""+question[idd]);

        frame_row.addView(btn_right, params3);

        btn_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {                       
                btn_right = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
                X1 = getRelativeLeft(btn_right);
                Y1 = getRelativeTop(btn_right);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(""+btn_right.getText().toString());
                selection ++;
                if (selection%2 ==1)
                {
                    selected_id1 = id_;
                    selected_color1 = b;                        
                    custom_toast("X1=" +X1 + "\nY1=" + Y1);                                             
                }
                else
                {
                    selected_id2 = id_;
                    selected_color2 = b;
                    X2 = getRelativeLeft(btn_right);
                    Y2 = getRelativeTop(btn_right);

                    custom_toast("X2=" +X2 + "\nY2=" + Y2);

                    // the first one 
                    btn_right = ((Button) findViewById(selected_id1));
                    anim1=new TranslateAnimation(0, (X2-X1), 0, (Y2-Y1)); 
                    anim1.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim1.setDuration(animationTime);
                    anim1.setAnimationListener(Game.this);  
                    btn_right.startAnimation(anim1);

                    // the second one
                    btn_right = ((Button) findViewById(selected_id2));
                    anim2=new TranslateAnimation(0, (X1-X2), 0, (Y1-Y2));
                    anim2.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim2.setDuration(animationTime);
                    anim2.setAnimationListener(Game.this);
                    btn_right.startAnimation(anim2);                                
                }

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
{

    if (animation == anim1)
    {           
        custom_toast("1 clear");
        btn_right = ((Button) findViewById(selected_id1));
        btn_right.clearAnimation();     // Line 426

    }
    if (animation == anim2)
    {           
        custom_toast("2 clear");
        btn_right = ((Button) findViewById(selected_id2));
        btn_right.clearAnimation();     
    }
}
```

## Logcat:

```
04-21 21:28:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(11341): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 21:28:00.728: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at com.abc.abc.Game.onAnimationEnd(Game.java:426)
```

## Question:

For info, if selection%2 ==1, it means user has only pressed the first button and is not yet ready for swap, and hence to record the id and its X, Y coordinates. If selection%2 ==0, it means user has pressed 2 buttons and is ready to swap after recording the 2nd's X and Y.

Also, the (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) coordinates are reporting correctly.

It runs into a NPE at line 426 `btn_right.clearAnimation();` (as specified above) . My question is, since all the buttons are inflated, and I have already setId for all the inflated buttons, why it would still runs out as a NPE at line 426, or actually how should I specify the 2 buttons that the user has touched so as to implement the swapping animation?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a list of buttons, you can create buttons and set their id, tags and onclicklistenners like this and add them to the button list:

```
 buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        button.setOnClickListener(customListenner);
        button.setAnimation(anim);
        button.setId(i);
        button.setTag(i);
        myLayout.addView(button);
        buttonList.add(button);
    }
```

and when you need to use the button again, just call with their id or tags from the list. (`buttonList.get(0).getId()`)

If you need different listenners, you can control them by using the unique tag check in if function and declare another action.

This is the method that I always use when I need to create and use animations on dynamic views programmatically.